# QWebView not showing page when JS involved

Tags: qt, windows-ce, qwebview

I successfully managed to compile Qt 4 including WebKit for WinCE. QWebView seems to run fine - I can load a HTML5 document and it gets displayed.

```
ui.webView->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);

ui.webView->setUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(QLatin1String("test.html")).absoluteFilePath()));
```

However, as soon as the page contains any JavaScript (even an empty script-tag already causes the problem), QWebView will only display a blank page.

The QWebInspector window can also not be shown, as it also just displays a blank window.

I doubt this is a common problem, so my question is, how I could dig into that issue. Is there any debug log for QWebView?
Unfortunately, there's no exception or assertion failure being thrown while execution.

Any ideas? :)
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**:
Here is the test code creating the problem. The first four lines of loadFinished are some test code to check valid pointers and whether I could call methods on QWebFrame at all. All code lines execute well until the evaluateJavaScript, where I get an access violation.

I could not post the HTML code inside setHtml, seems to be forbidden by Stackoverflow.

```
ce0::ce0(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
ui.setupUi(this);

connect(ui.webView, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(loadFinished(bool)));

ui.webView->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
ui.webView->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, true);
ui.webView->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);
ui.webView->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
//ui.webView->setUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(QLatin1String("test.html")).absoluteFilePath()));
ui.webView->setHtml(...);
}

void ce0::loadFinished(bool ok) {
    QWebPage* p = ui.webView->page();
    QWebFrame* f = p->mainFrame();  
    QString qs = f->title();

bool x = ui.webView->page()->settings()->testAttribute( QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled );

f->evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"content\").innerHTML = \"Whatever\";");
}
```

Comment: could you provide the javascript and html in question?

Comment: Any HTML / JS will do, even a simple stub with html, head, title, body tag. As soon as I insert a script-tag, the page won't load. When I execute the given html/js in a desktop browser (Safari, Chrome,...) the JS executes fine and the inspector shows no error.

Comment: thats odd. i had my own share of oddities when working with qts webkit, but i cannot really diagnose it with the info i have. My experience tells me that the js is (or qt tries to) executed before the interpreter is loaded and does nothing. I usually work around that by connecting to the webviews' `loadFinished()`signal.

Comment: also, if you're using QWebInspector, be sure to set `DeveloperExtrasEnabled` to `true`, but I guess you know that already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To dig into this I've connected the loadFinished signal and called the javascript function I want to execute explicitly (via QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript). Now I run into an access violation. Looking at the call stack, the execution breaks at StackBounds::checkConsistency. isGrowingDownward seems to distinguish between operating systems by #define-blocks. There's also one for WinCE. I compiled with the neccessary #define (WTF_OS_WINCE) but the problem does not get solved.

Comment: what does that function return? `yourWebViewNameHere->page()->settings()->testAttribute( QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled );`

Comment: I evaluated testAttribute within loadFinished slot and it returns true. I've set both attributes JavaScriptEnabled and DeveloperExtrasEnabled within the constructor of my window.

Comment: I've edited my question, it contains my test code now...